# Z3_get_numeral_double API gives different result in z3 version 4.8.10 compared to z3 version 4.8.4

Tags: z3

we have been using c++ binding z3 version 4.8.4 for some time now for constraint satisfiability. Our constraints can also have floating number/double to representing propositional constraints. A Sample constraints would be:

CarModel=M1 implies chasisLength=999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999.0 (assume very small unit of measure for chasisLength)

Based on our understanding of z3 public API, we identified one way of initializing real sort variable in z3 with double value and retrieve the double value from real sort z3::expr. However, our way doesn’t seems to be consistent across z3 version. The below c++ code snippet is trying to demonstrate the problem by running the same code snippet against different z3 versions(4.8.10 versus 4.8.4). Is this a known issue with Z3_get_numeral_double API?

Also Is there some better way of initializing real sort expr with double value and retrieving double value from real sort z3 expression?

```
z3::context c;
z3::solver z3Solver(c);

z3::expr floatFam = c.real_const("Length");
std::string floatValue("999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999"); // 9 repeated 54 times
char* endBuf = NULL;
const double doubleValue = strtod(floatValue.c_str(), &endBuf); // strtod return 1.0 * 10e+54
char buffer[100] = "";
sprintf_s(buffer, 100, "%.16g", doubleValue);
z3::expr floatValueExpr = c.real_val(buffer);
z3::expr lengthBoolFlag = c.bool_const("lengthConst");

z3Solver.add(lengthBoolFlag == (floatFam == floatValueExpr)); // assert that there is equivalencne relation between lengthConst=true and length=1.0 * 10e+54

z3::expr modelFam = c.int_const("ModelConst");
z3::expr value1 = c.int_val(1);
z3::expr value2 = c.int_val(2);
z3::expr value3 = c.int_val(3);

z3Solver.add((modelFam == value1) || (modelFam == value2) || (modelFam == value3)); // add assert to solver stating ModelConst can have three possible values 1, 2, 3
z3Solver.add(z3::implies((modelFam == value1), lengthBoolFlag)); // add assert stating if ModelConst=1 then lengthConst has be true
z3Solver.add(modelFam == value1); // assert ModelConst=1

z3::check_result satVerdict = z3Solver.check();

if (z3::sat == satVerdict)
{
    const z3::model z3Model = z3Solver.get_model();
    z3::expr realExpr = z3Model.eval(floatFam); // get the solution for length from the z3 model
    double z3DblValue = 0;
    if (realExpr.is_numeral(z3DblValue))
    {
        z3::expr numeratorExpr = realExpr.numerator(); // get the numerator expr from realExpr
        z3::expr denominatorExpr = realExpr.denominator(); // get the denominator expr from realExpr
        **double numerator = Z3_get_numeral_double(c, numeratorExpr); // When run with z3 version 4.8.10 this returns 9.999 * 10e+53 which is different what was set in the assert, however when run with z3 version 4.8.4 it returns 1.0 * 10e+54 which exactly what was set in the assert**
        double denominator = Z3_get_numeral_double(c, denominatorExpr); // this returns 1.0
        z3DblValue = numerator / denominator; // 9.999 * 10e+53 is retrieved as solution which violates implies and equivalence assert above
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible that there's a bug, but it's very hard to tell from your example whether there is one. Z3 reals are not floating-point numbers, they are proper, mathematical real numbers, not approximate and not truncated. Z3 also supports floats, but you're not using them here. I suggest you print the solver object so that you can see what constraints it holds, and then the model, so that you can see exactly what Z3 thinks the model looks like.

Comment: I tried print the solver object, z3 model and z3::expr return by eval API on z3 model. All of them are printing the expected value. It is only at the line below double value gets rounded off(also mentioned as code comment in the original post)                  
         
double numerator = Z3_get_numeral_double(c, numeratorExpr);                                                     Hence I suspect a bug in Z3_get_numeral_double API with z3 version 4.8.10